# What is the difference between the headers added by HttpAddRequestHeaders and the ones sent by HttpSendRequest

Tags: c++, wininet

I'm dealing with WinInet and I want to know what is the practical difference between the headers that are set by the HttpAddRequestHeaders function (using a HttpOpenRequest handle) and that ones that are sent by the HttpSendRequest function.

To simplify my code there are one better place to define such headers? I would want to avoid deal with these two ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Microsoft documentation:

- [HttpSendRequest function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384247(v=vs.85).aspx)

  > The function also lets the client specify optional data to send to the
  >   HTTP server immediately following the request headers. This feature is
  >   generally used for "write" operations such as PUT and POST.
- [HttpAddRequestHeaders function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384227(v=vs.85).aspx)

  - HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD

    Adds the header if it does not exist. Used with HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE.
  - HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD_IF_NEW

    Adds the header only if it does not already exist; otherwise, an error is returned.
  - HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_COALESCE

    Coalesces headers of the same name.
  - HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_COALESCE_WITH_COMMA

    Coalesces headers of the same name. For example, adding "Accept: text/*" followed by "Accept: audio/*" with this flag results in the formation of the single header "Accept: text/*, audio/*". This causes the first header found to be coalesced. It is up to the calling application to ensure a cohesive scheme with respect to coalesced/separate headers.
  - HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_COALESCE_WITH_SEMICOLON

    Coalesces headers of the same name using a semicolon.
  - HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE

    Replaces or removes a header. If the header value is empty and the header is found, it is removed. If not empty, the header value is replaced.

So if all you want to do is "add request headers", either API will give you the same functionality.

If you want to do "something special" (like "coalesce headers") you might to choose one or the other API.

'Hope that helps

Comment: So, there are no differences at all, right? You must agree that these two places where to define headers are confused. I can send a file (xml, but it can be binary also...), using "multipart/form-data" header set with HttpAddRequestHeaders function. I do not use the HttpSendRequest function to set headers.

My last question, to finally clarify everything, is: Is there "n" levels of headers? This question is embased by the fact of there are two different places where we can set them. Only if there are "more than one level" of HTTP Headers these two places makes a little sense.

Comment: 1. Please don't confuse the Microsoft API calls with the HTTP protocols.  2. You can learn more about HTTP headers here: [rfc 2616 Section 4.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), [rfc 822 Section 3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822#section-3.1).  3. The two APIs offer slightly different options.  Whichever you choose is really just a matter of personal preference - that's all :)  'Hope that helps!